Is there any rest api call to fetch the interchanges between two branches in perforce
I see we have a P4 command to get the interchanges between two branches through command line.
But, Is there any rest api call to fetch the interchanges between two branches in perforce ? To display in my web application.

No.  The only REST API provided for P4D and supported by Perforce (AFAIK) is Swarm's.  Something like p4 interchanges would probably live under the "files" or "changes" section of the API, but there's nothing in either that has anything to do with integration or branching.
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/swarm/Content/Swarm/swarm-api-endpoint-files.html#Files__Swarm_files
If you can stand up a web API server in any language I think this would be pretty easy to implement (even if you had to call out to the p4 executable instead of using one of the language bindings, you could probably use the -F flag to do all the formatting instead of having to parse stdout).
Here's a very trivial example using FastAPI and P4Python:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from P4 import P4

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/interchanges/")
async def run_interchanges(to_file: str, from_file: str):
    with P4().connect() as p4:
        return p4.run_interchanges(from_file, to_file)


